# Is there a TweenMax equivalent in Java

Tags: java, android, flash, actionscript-3, animation

I'm still relatively new to Java and Android development, so I'm still unfamiliar with the multitudes of libraries available for use, particularly for animation.  Where I'm from (the Flash world), we have access to several 3rd-party tweening engines that make life very easy for us when we want to programmatically move things around the stage without relying on the (vastly inferior) built-in Adobe tween APIs.  One of the most popular is Greensock's [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/)

Looking at the way Android handles tweening natively, it appears to be very cumbersome compared to what I'm used to.  I'm curious if there's a TweenMax-equivalent library out there for Android that makes animation sequencing equally easy to write in-code, with the benefits of smart intellisense, rather than having to write them all out in an external animation.xml file in the res folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry to reply so lately to this thread, but there is a more framework-independent answer to your question: the java Universal Tween Engine.

http://code.google.com/p/java-universal-tween-engine/

[image]

This library started as a way to mimic TweenMax/Lite functionality in any java project, and ended as a complete, independent, tweening engine. It is optimized for **Android** (no dynamic allocation), but can be used in virtually every java project, being a **Swing UI** or an **OpenGL game**...

You shouldn't be lost if you come from TweenMax world, since the base syntax is quite similar:

```
Tween.to(myObject, POSITION, 1000).target(20, 30).ease(Elastic.OUT).start(myManager);
```

Timelines are a bit different though, but are still easy to understand:

```
Timeline.createSequence()
    // First, set all objects to their initial positions
    .push(Tween.set(...))
    .push(Tween.set(...))
    .push(Tween.set(...))

    // Wait 1s
    .pushPause(1000)

    // Move the objects around, one after the other
    .push(Tween.to(...))
    .push(Tween.to(...))
    .push(Tween.to(...))

    // Then, move the objects around at the same time
    .beginParallel()
        .push(Tween.to(...))
        .push(Tween.to(...))
        .push(Tween.to(...))
    .end()

    // And repeat the whole sequence 2 times
    .repeatYoyo(2, 500)

    // Let's go!
    .start(myManager);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks :) Also, you can see it in action here (requires Google Chrome to enable webgl): http://www.aurelienribon.com/universal-tween-engine/gwt/demo.html Every animation (from splash-screen to launcher) was done with the lib. It's a bit buggy since it uses an alpha version of a gaming java-to-html framework.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use XML files, you can use Animation, AnimationSet and the various Interpolator implementations. Android 3.0 however provides a much more powerful animation API.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on that.  At the same time, I read in several places that you should be careful with those animation APIs as they're quite intense in terms of taxing the CPU.  The same can be said of the native Flash tween apis, which is why there's such a strong market for 3rd party engines.  I thought that might be the case here too... or maybe they simply solve the problem by not relying on Java at all and simply use NDK instead?  I'll have a look into the 3.0 API, though.

Comment: These animation APIs don't do much, a 3rd party engine would not be less CPU intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I have found something close to what I was asking for.  There's a port of Cocos2D for Android here : 
[Cocos2D for android](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android-1/)

It's not completely bug free (thinking mostly of the particle system here), but it offers a wide range of animation and display functions for the sorts of things you'd use Greensock for.  It even comes with a Box2D port on top of it all.

Comment: FYI, there is an up-to-date version here: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x but it uses the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Contents) and OP wanted to use Java instead. An alternative (which also needs the NDK) would be Open Frameworks which has several addons to choose from: ofxTweener, ofxTweenzor, ofxSoso, etc.